# REST API connected to Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently developing a REST API on my webserver for handling calls towards a Facebook application. This way I can check if the user has a valid license in our license database before allowing him/her to post to Facebook.

I'm using two separate calls at the moment, one to authorize the client with Facebook and store his/her access token in our license database. And another to actually publish to Facebook (and also other social platforms).

The Authorization seems to work. But the publishing always returns

```
{
    "success": false,
    "error": {
        "message": "(#200) User must have accepted TOS",
        "type": "FacebookRequestAppException",
        "code": 200
    }
}
```

I am currently working with a development app (on Facebook), without the proper permissions submitted, would this be the issue? And if so, how can I test it if I'm not allowed to use it?

The PHP code that triggers the Exception:

```
try {
    $app = ( new FacebookRequest($app_session, 'POST', $post_url, array( 'appsecret_proof' => $appsecret_proof ) ) )->execute()->getGraphObject();

    $output = array_merge( array( 'success' => true ), $output );

} catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
    $output = array_merge( $output, array( 'success' => false, 'error' => array( 'message' => $e->getMessage(), 'type'=> 'FacebookRequestAppException', 'code' => $e->getCode() ) ) );
}
```

### Edit:

The call:

```
        $app_id = '1503912413161954';
        $app_secret = '<app_secret_censored>';

        $user_access_token = (string)$this->getIdentity()->facebook_token;
        $app_access_token = (string)$this->getIdentity()->facebook_app_token;
        $license_id = (int)$this->getIdentity()->license_id;
        $user_account_type = (string)$this->getIdentity()->user_account_type;
        $redirect_url = 'http://api.example.com/authorize';

        include 'lib/fb_authorize.php';
```

The authorization code - have in mind that it's not yet complete, and that I'm using Yii Framwork as well to add connectivity to our database:

```
<?php 
$http_session = new CHttpSession;
$http_session->setTimeout(60);
$http_session->setSessionName('fb_session');
$http_session->open();

require( 'vendor/autoload.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id, $app_secret);
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url, $app_id, $app_secret);


if ( isset( $user_access_token ) ) {
    $user_session = new FacebookSession( $user_access_token );
    try {   
        if ( !$user_session->validate() ) {
        $user_session = null;
        }
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        $user_session = null;
        $output = array_merge( $output, array( 'success' => false, 'error' => array( 'message' => $e->getMessage(), 'type'=> 'ExxicaUserSessionException', 'code' => $e->getCode() ) ) );
    }
} else {  
    try {
        $user_session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    } catch( Exception $e ) {
        $user_session = null;
        $output = array_merge( $output, array( 'success' => false, 'error' => array( 'message' => $e->getMessage(), 'type'=> 'ExxicaUserSessionException', 'code' => $e->getCode() ) ) );
    }
}

if( isset( $user_session ) ) {
    $appsecret_proof= hash_hmac('sha256', $user_session->getToken(), $app_secret);
    if( isset( $http_session['getpages'] ) ) {
        try {
            // Get Page ID
            $user = ( new FacebookRequest($user_session, 'GET', '/me/accounts', array( 'appsecret_proof' => $appsecret_proof ) ) )->execute()->getGraphObject();

            $output = array( 'success' => true, 'user' => $user );

        } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
            $output = array( 'success' => false, 'error' => array( 'message' => $e->getMessage(), 'type'=> 'FacebookRequestUserException', 'code' => $e->getCode() ) );
        }
    }

    try {
        $app_session = new FacebookSession( $app_access_token );
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        $app_session = null;
        $output = array_merge( $output, array( 'success' => false, 'error' => array( 'message' => $e->getMessage(), 'type'=> 'ExxicaAppSessionException', 'code' => $e->getCode() ) ) );
    }

    $c = new CDbCriteria();
    $c->compare( 'id', $license_id );
    $l = _Licenses::model()->find( $c );
    $l->facebook_token = $user_session->getToken();
    $l->facebook_app_token = $app_session->getToken();
    $l->save();

    $output = array_merge( $output, array( 'success' => true, 'user_token' => $l->facebook_token ) );
} else {
    header( 'Location: '.$helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'manage_pages','publish_actions','public_profile' ) ) );
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you add the code you are using to get all the permissions you need from the user?

Comment: Added the authorization code.